# Flutter ImagePicker error "attribute android:requestLegacyExternalStorage not found"

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions

I use [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) in my flutter project. It says "API < 29 ----> Add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" as an attribute to the  tag in AndroidManifest.xml. The attribute is false by default on apps targeting Android Q."

In `build.gradle`, it has `compileSdkVersion 28` under `android`, and `minSdkVersion 16` and `targetSdkVersion 28` under `defaultConfig`. I'm not familiar with this, but I assume these fits the `API<29` condition. So I added the attribute.

Then my project won't compile anymore with error saying "AAPT: error: attribute android:requestLegacyExternalStorage not found." It compiles if I delete `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`. However since it specifically asks to add this attribute, I want to figure this out to avoid any potential problems like rejection on iOS for permission related issues.

After adding the attribute, my `AndroidManifest.xml` looks like:
[image]

What should I do about this? Thank you!

Comment: "_It compiles if I delete android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"_" Means no more issue?

Comment: Yes, but it specifically asks to add this attribute. I want to avoid any potential problems like rejection on iOS for permission related issues.

Comment: I guess it won't affect IOS since you added in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Perhaps use IOS device to test?

Comment: I mean to avoid issues that are similar to the rejection in App Store on iOS . Not sure what google will do if I don't add this attribute.

Comment: Adding android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" to manifest file only makes sense for sdk version 29. For devices running Android Q/10. That doc is wrong.

Comment: That's soothing. @blackapps Thank you! I'll simply delete this attribute then.

Answer (score 3):

To solve that issue, in "build.gradle (Project)", set the "compileSdkVersion", "buildToolsVersion" and "targetSdkVersion" as 29 like this:

```
buildToolsVersion = “29.0.0”
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 29
targetSdkVersion = 29
supportLibVersion = “28.0.0”
```

Comment: buildToolsVersion doesn't exist inside the whole android folder